# Can I enter Iran with an expired Iranian passport, while being in possession of a second passport?

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens, iran

I am a Canadian citizen and I am traveling to Iran (back home) this December. My Iranian passport expired on 17/05/2015. I was wondering if I can use it. I want to renew my passport in Iran because it is much cheaper there.

Comment: If you're male and haven't done Military service, remember to get the passport stamp from the embassy permitting you to leave Iran

Answer (score 8):

> Nationals of Iran are allowed to enter with an expired passport.

[This is noted in Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IR&DE=IR&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=CA&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the system which airlines use to verify passenger documents prior to boarding, so you should have no trouble boarding your flight. Present your Iranian passport when you check in to your flight. (You probably will need to present both passports here due to airport transits.)

Remember that Iran does not generally recognize dual citizenship, so you should not need to show your Canadian passport to Iranian officials. You do need to bring it with you, though, because you need to show it to the airline for your return flight to Canada. [Read more on traveling with two citizenships.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/3221)

Comment: Does "not recognize" mean that they don't allow Iranian nationals to keep a second nationality?

Comment: @Fiksdal It means they treat them as Iranian citizens and disregard the other citizenship. So such people may be required to do their military service, may not be allowed to contact the embassy of their other nationality if they're arrested, and so on.

Comment: Just because Timatic says that doesn't mean airlines cannot have additional requirements to let them on board. Timatic also says that US green card holders do not need a passport to go to the US, but how many airlines will board them on an international flight without a passport?

Comment: @user102008 I haven't got the slightest idea. And I don't see any relevance to this situation.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this 5 years ego. I have Australian citizenship and entered Iran with an expired Iranin passport. They don't care about your second passport. It doesn't matter if you have a valid Canadian passport or that I had an Australian passport. What matters is that you can enter Iran with an expired Iranian passport but you leave can't leave without getting a new one. So, as long as you renew while in Iran, you are sorted. That is eactly what I did 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Qatar Airways lets you fly to Iran with an expired Iranian passport.

Source: [Qatar Airways Travel & Entry Requirements](https://www.qatarairways.com/en/travel-alerts/requirements.html) (accessed 2021-04-28).